# Returning all possible vertex coloring combinations in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am required to write a method three_color(graph) that will take a graph in as an input, and return all possible vertex colorings of the graph, including those that are invalid. We are representing graphs using dictionaries, and the  output should be a list of dictionaries.

```
three_color({“A” : [“B”], “B” : [“A”]}) should return 

{“A” : 1, “B” : 1}, {“A” : 1, “B” : 2}, {“A” : 1, “B” : 3}, {“A” : 2, “B” : 1}, {“A” : 2, “B” : 2}, {“A” : 2, “B” : 3}, {“A” : 3, “B” : 1}, {“A” : 3, “B” : 2}, {“A” : 3, “B” : 3}
```

I'm having issues coming up with a solution on how to write this method, as we are not allowed to use any libraries aside from copy to help us.

I'm new to python, so I'm not sure if there is a simple solution I am overlooking. And assistance, or guidance, is greatly appreciated.
This is what I've been trying to work with:

```
def three_color(graph):
    vertices = []
    colorings = []
    color = {}
    for key in graph:
        vertices.append(key)
    for v in vertices:
        color[v] = 1
    colorings.append(copy.copy(color))

    for v in vertices:
        for v2 in vertices:
            for i in range(1,4):
                for j in range(1,4):
                    color[v] = i
                    color[v2] = j
                    colorings.append(copy.copy(color))

    #Get rid of duplicates
    new_c = []
    for c in colorings:
        if c not in new_c:
            new_c.append(c)

    return new_c
```

I'm aware this is completely wrong, but I cannot think through these for loops properly.

Comment: Asking for homework help is okay, but we expect the poster to make an effort of their own first. What have you tried so far? Where are you getting stuck? Please read the [tour] and [ask].

Comment: I've tried several for loops. My main issue stems from the fact that my solutions involve a number of nested for loops equal to the number of vertices, which would not only be a lot, it'd also require new code for every possible number of vertices.

Comment: Please include the code you've attempted so far, show the output or if there is an error include the full traceback, and show what the desired output is for this input.

Comment: All of my attempts have given me missing orderings. Like I said, I'm more or less looking for guidance, or perhaps a 'hint' to help get me started on a solution. I've spent several hours on this already, and I just need a point in the right direction.

Comment: Is this http://wiki.c2.com/?GraphThreeColoring the problem you are trying to solve? Even if your code isn't working, include it so people can help with next steps. Have you created a pseudocode solution?

Comment: I added my current attempt. @Zev that is similar to the problem I'm trying to solve, but this code does not care if it is a valid coloring or not, I simply need all possible combinations.

Answer (score 1):

Because this is a homework question, I'll give a pseudocode solution, and you can implement it yourself, and hopefully learn more that way.

I'm partial to recursion, so I'll use it in this solution.

```
take a graph as an argument:
    if the graph is empty, return the graph
    recursively color all the elements except the first, store the result as "tail"
    store the first element of the list as "head"
    for every element of tail, refered to as "element":
        add "head, color 1" + element to a final results list
        add "head, color 2" + element to a final results list
        add "head, color 3" + element to a final results list
    return final results
```

Comment: This helps out a lot. But is this returning a list of dictionaries like this? {“A” : 1, “B” : 1}, {“A” : 1, “B” : 2}, {“A” : 1, “B” : 3}, {“A” : 2, “B” : 1}, {“A” : 2, “B” : 2}, {“A” : 2, “B” : 3}, {“A” : 3, “B” : 1}, {“A” : 3, “B” : 2}, {“A” : 3, “B” : 3} It seems like it is returning a list of single colorings.

Comment: This is psuedocode, it can return whatever type you like. I wrote it intending to return a list of dictionaries though, and it can do that.